# Moving UITextField up with keyboard - changes in swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, xcode4.2

I had this function to move certain textfields upwards, when the keyboards would block their view - I'm sure you all know about this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let center: NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name?.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name?.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

}

But when I recently updated to swift 4.2, these stopped working, and these suggestions came up:

Replace 'UIKeyboardDidShow' with 'UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification' &

Replace 'UIKeyboardWillHide' with 'UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification

But when I pressed "fix", I get the error (x2):

Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'UIResponder'

It kind of seems like a bug to me? That xCode can't accept it's own changes?? Anybody came across this and knows what to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object: nil)
```

More info use this link :- [enter link description here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/16/7/fixing-the-keyboard-notificationcenter)

I hope this will help you :D
Thanks

Comment: Works like a charm (Y)
Just wierd that xCode doesn't change it to that itself, if you ask me!

Comment: @AntonBjerg sometime happen when change class hierarchy :D enjoy